# docker run process from terminal

Tags: linux, shell, docker, terminal, lxc

Run container:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker run -it centos:7.7.1908 /bin/bash
[root@79d4ba3a2080 /]#
```

Host execution:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ps aux|grep /bin/bash
root      10124  0.0  2.7 385800 51548 pts/1    Sl+  14:25   0:00 docker run -it centos:7.7.1908 /bin/bash
root      10155  0.0  0.0  11828  1740 pts/0    Ss+  14:25   0:00 /bin/bash
root      10197  0.0  0.0 112728   976 pts/2    S+   14:27   0:00 grep --color=auto /bin/bash
```

View container running process fd:
container running process (stdin, stdout, stderr) point to pts/0.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ll /proc/10155/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May   8 14:25 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May   8 14:25 1 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May   8 14:25 2 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May   8 14:29 255 -> /dev/pts/0
```

Test 1:

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo "hello" > /proc/10155/fd/0
```

container display result:

```
[root@79d4ba3a2080 /]# hello
```

Test 2:

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo "hello" > /dev/pts/0
```

host display result:

```
[root@localhost ~]# tty
/dev/pts/0
[root@localhost ~]# hello
```

The result shows that in the host pts / 0, the container is not responding .
What is the problem with 'Test 2'?

Why is it not displayed in the container?

What did docker do?

If there is any relevant information, please let me know, Thank you.

Understand:

I simulated the type phenomenon with the following command.

Mount directories, which are mirrored by docker CentOS 7

```
[root@localhost test]# mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e6e24960aabfb790c893d0d1e419cb34f97b92824941ab74b01348ef96c99412-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/075bf06b50f9bc5fc2111b5e1c831f7f1304e3310a448e323e71ca9e7d83ba55/diff,upperdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e6e24960aabfb790c893d0d1e419cb34f97b92824941ab74b01348ef96c99412/diff,workdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e6e24960aabfb790c893d0d1e419cb34f97b92824941ab74b01348ef96c99412/work /project/test/t222
```

Creat Pid namespace:

```
[root@localhost t222]# unshare -u -i -p -m -n -f  --mount-proc /bin/bash
[root@localhost t222]# pivot_root . .
[root@localhost t222]# for e in "proc proc proc/" "sysfs sysfs sys/" "devtmpfs devtmpfs dev/" "devpts devpts dev/pts/" ; do mount -t ${e} ; done
[root@localhost t222]# df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay        overlay    17G   14G  3.8G  79% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  898M     0  898M   0% /dev
```

Test file:

In new namespace:

```
[root@localhost t222]# vi 123.txt
```

In Host:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ps -ef
'''
root      28295  28030  0 5月10 pts/4   00:00:00 unshare -u -i -p -m -n -f --mount-proc /bin/bash
root      28297  28295  0 5月10 pts/4   00:00:00 /bin/bash
root      29921  28297  0 09:52 pts/4    00:00:00 vi 123.txt
```

View process information:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ll /proc/28295/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 5月  11 09:52 /proc/28295/cwd -> /
[root@localhost ~]# ll /proc/28297/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 5月  11 09:52 /proc/28297/cwd -> /
[root@localhost ~]# ll /proc/30272/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 5月  11 10:06 /proc/30272/cwd -> /
[root@localhost ~]# ll /proc/30272/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 5月  11 10:06 0 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 5月  11 10:06 1 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 5月  11 10:06 2 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 5月  11 10:06 3 -> /.123.txt.swp [red, soft connection does not exist]
[root@localhost ~]# touch /.123.txt.swp
[root@localhost ~]# ll /proc/30272/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 5月  11 10:06 0 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 5月  11 10:06 1 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 5月  11 10:06 2 -> /dev/pts/4
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 5月  11 10:06 3 -> /.123.txt.swp [normal]
```

Summary:

The process information seen in the host is the process information in the new namespace, "ll /proc/30272/fd" show soft connection does not exist, It's based on the old namespace, mainly "**pivot_root**", modified the running directory of all current processes

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write to `/proc/10124/fd/0` in "Test 1"? I don't see why writing to `/proc/10155/fd/0` would write to the docker container's stdin.

Comment: confirm to write /proc/10155/fd/0,  would write to the docker container's stdout.

Comment: stdin stdout stderr of the container process points to pts/0 and writes data to pts/0. why does stdout of the container process not respond

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)  or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

You did not map the pts devices to the container, add this parameter in the run command:
`--volume /dev/pts:/dev/pts`

Reference:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

```
$ docker run  -it --rm  --volume /dev/pts:/dev/pts centos bash
[root@b5010471931d /]# ps aux
USER        PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root          1  0.5  0.0  12024  3168 pts/7    Ss   10:57   0:00 bash
root         16  0.0  0.0  43960  3324 pts/7    R+   10:57   0:00 ps aux
```

On host:

```
# echo hello_from_host > /dev/pts/7
```

In container:

```
[root@b5010471931d /]# hello_from_host
```

Comment: mount /dev/pts , a new terminal will be added to the host .   I want to know why test2 is like this